# How do I find the day of week of a date-time field in postgres?

Tags: postgresql, datetime

How do I find the day of week of a date-time field? I'm trying to extract the the day of the week from a column in a sql query in postgres. While

```
SELECT EXTRACT(DOW FROM '2011-07-07')
```

works, the following query does not work and I can't figure it out:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(DOW FROM TIMESTAMP date) as day
FROM purchases GROUP BY day;
```

It's like postgres won't let me find the day of the week for fields but only constants. How do I find the day of week for a field?

Answer (score 3):

The whole issue revolves around `CAST`ing and quirky PostgreSQL syntax.

`CAST`ing strings as `DATE`s:

It's very simple - your first line of code:

```
ntest=# SELECT EXTRACT(DOW FROM '2011-07-07');
ERROR:  function pg_catalog.date_part(unknown, unknown) is not unique
LINE 1: SELECT EXTRACT(DOW FROM '2011-07-07');
               ^
HINT:  Could not choose a best candidate function. You might need to add explicit type casts.
ntest=#
```

does **not** work. This is because, as far as PostreSQL  is concerned, '2011-07-07' is just a string literal, not a `DATE`. This does work:

```
ntest=# SELECT EXTRACT(DOW FROM DATE '2011-07-07');
 date_part 
-----------
         4
(1 row)
```

Note the extra `DATE` that `CAST`s the string as such. You can also `CAST` it this way:

```
ntest=# SELECT EXTRACT(DOW FROM '2011-07-07'::DATE);
 date_part 
-----------
         4
```

This double colon (::) is very much a PostreSQL thing. It's really quite "obvious", once you grasp the PostgreSQL syntax (it had me stumped for a couple of minutes!)

### A date field:

```
ntest=# \d orders;
       Table "public.orders"
   Column    |  Type   | Modifiers 
-------------+---------+-----------
 ldate       | date    | 
 customer_id | integer | 
 amount      | integer |
```

So, we have a date field - with records as below:

```
ntest=# SELECT * FROM orders;
   ldate    | customer_id | amount 
------------+-------------+--------
 2009-10-08 |           3 |   3000
 2009-10-08 |           3 |   1500
 2009-11-20 |           2 |   1560
 2008-05-20 |           4 |   2060
(4 rows)
```

So, to get the "day of week" from a date (note the **two** `FROM`s - doesn't work without the `FROM` between brackets):

```
ntest=# SELECT EXTRACT(DOW FROM ldate) FROM orders;
 date_part 
-----------
         4
         4
         5
         2
(4 rows)
```

### Now, for a timestamp field:

```
ntest=# \d timestamptest;
           Table "public.timestamptest"
 Column |            Type             | Modifiers 
--------+-----------------------------+-----------
 x      | timestamp without time zone |
```

And:

```
ntest=# SELECT * FROM timestamptest;
             x              
----------------------------
 2016-04-18 22:52:30.020979
(1 row)
```

And DOW (again, note the two `FROM`s):

```
ntest=# SELECT EXTRACT(DOW FROM x) FROM timestamptest;
 date_part 
-----------
         1
```

Quirky syntax (the double colon also OK, if you want to be **really** explicit), but it works fine once you've mastered it.

Comment: The `EXTRACT(DOW FROM x)` is what the SQL standard requires. That "quirky syntax" is not Postgres specific. And `'2011-07-07'` is a **string** constant in SQL, not a `DATE`. The SQL standard for a `DATE` constant would be `DATE '2011-07-07'` - again nothing specific to Postgres.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I think the quirky syntax is referring to the `::` casting but I agree. It's not obvious what is referring to so it can be misinterpreted (so it's probably better to remove it.